# Return values for an exact change function

Tags: python, function, return-value

I am writing a program that takes a certain amount of change and outputs the change using the fewest coins possible. For some reason my exact change function is not returning values. It is printing the values that I want due to the main function, but it is not returning the values of the variables I defined under the exact_change function. What could be the problem?

```
input_val = int(input())

def exact_change(user_total):

    # Defines variables and returns them
    num_dollars = input_val // 100
    rem = input_val % 100
    num_quarters = rem // 25
    rem = rem % 25
    num_dimes = rem // 10
    rem = rem % 10
    num_nickels = rem // 5
    rem = rem % 5
    num_pennies = rem
    return(num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    
    num_dollars, num_quarters, num_dimes, num_nickels, num_pennies = exact_change(input_val)

    if input_val <= 0: 
        print("no change")
    else:
        # calculate Dollars
        num_dollars = input_val // 100
        converted_dollar = str(num_dollars)
        rem = input_val % 100
        if num_dollars == 1: 
            print(converted_dollar + ' dollar')
        elif num_dollars > 1: 
            print(converted_dollar + ' dollars')
    
        # calculate Quarters
        num_quarters = rem // 25
        converted_quarter = str(num_quarters)
        rem = rem % 25
        if num_quarters == 1:
            print(converted_quarter + ' quarter')
        elif num_quarters > 1:
            print(converted_quarter + ' quarters')
    
        # calculate Dimes
        num_dimes = rem // 10
        converted_dime = str(num_dimes)
        rem = rem % 10
        if num_dimes == 1:
            print(converted_dime + ' dime')
        elif num_dimes > 1:
            print(converted_dime + ' dimes')
    
        # calculate Nickels
        num_nickels = rem // 5
        converted_nickel = str(num_nickels)
        rem = rem % 5
        if num_nickels==1:
            print(converted_nickel + ' nickel')
        elif num_nickels > 1:
            print(converted_nickel + ' nickels')
    
        # calculate Pennies
        num_pennies = rem
        converted_penny = str(num_pennies)
        if num_pennies == 1:
            print(converted_penny + ' penny')
        elif num_pennies > 1:
            print(converted_penny + ' pennies')
```

Comment: The code for your exact change function is not indented. In fact, a lot of this appears indented incorrectly and wouldn't run at all without error. Can you verify your indents and edit this post?

Comment: I just added indentations

Comment: "For some reason my exact change function is not returning values." Why do you believe this? Exactly what happens, beginning to end, when you run the program? Exactly how is that different from what you expect to happen? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make sure that *other people can observe the problem with the exact code that you give us*. If you "fixed" the problem by adding code under `if __name__ == '__main__'`, then you should **not** give us that code. And again: tell us **what happens**, not what "doesn't happen".

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are taking an input of user_total for the exact change function, but then never use the input. It should help if you change the start of the function to this...

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    input_val = user_total # set input_val as user_total
    num_dollars = input_val // 100
    rem = input_val % 100
```

or this

```
def exact_change(user_total):
    num_dollars = user_total // 100 # change input_val to user_total
    rem = user_total % 100 # change input_val to user_total
```